# time formats to keyword replacement using python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

can u please tell me how to write regular expression to match all time formats such as given below

```
2-sec,
0-second,
1-min,
1 mins,
4 minutes
5-minute

re=re.sub('[0-9].[{minutes|mins|sec|second|seconds|minute}]','TIME443"',"1 mins is value is 4 minutes value 5-minute")
```

there is some mistake in my re pleaese correct it

please tell me how to write regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s="2-sec"
>>> re.match('(\d).(m|s)',s).group(1,2)
('2', 's')
>>> s='2-min'
>>> re.match('(\d).(m|s)',s).group(1,2)
('2', 'm')
```

this would ignore any following characters.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should match all of your samples:

```
r"(\d+[- ](?:sec\w*|min\w*))"
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with: `'TIME443"'` as a replace string. This shows how the regex can find what you're looking for:

```
import re
search_str = "1 mins is value is 4 minutes value 5-minute"
found = re.findall(r"(\d+[- ](?:sec\w*|min\w*))", search_str)
print found
>> ['1 mins', '4 minutes', '5-minute']
```